# How to remove local notification after fired notification in IOS

Tags: ios

I am working on a project where I fire a local notification frequently also repeat notification.
After fired notification, if I delete the application and install it again (without opening it), I get all the old notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}
 *and then set remaining all notification in*
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-(void)clearNotifications
{
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 1];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i want to remove local notification after again installing application. So without opening application how to call cancelAllLocalNotifications method?

Answer (score 0):

```
put your code in App did finish launching method.so, when app launch then it's cancel the all notification.
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

//cancel All notification when app is launch
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    return YES;
}
```

Pls note that it cancel the all notification. if u want to cancel any particular notification then set it's tag and using tag cancel this notification.

Comment: After removing application if i again install application without open it.then how application call that method ? that was my question and i am facing problem on it

Comment: you write code in this delegate method.- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: Read more about this method in delegate class.and choose your option with appropriate condition.

Comment: which delegate method is called at remove application time?

Comment: There is no any method call when you remove application.But you can set it's logically like, Store variable in NSUser default in Application did finish launching.and conditionally check if data is not available then call notification otherwise cancel notification.

Comment: Means when you delete app then clear the NSUserdefaul otherwise you get the notification.When u remove the app then automatically also cancel the notification.Not need any extra code.